# How can I use Js to click a div and change another div's settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code missing unneeded info.

```
<div>   
  <div id="one" class="button"></div>
  <div id="two" class="button"></div>       
</div>

<div>
    <div class="Home tab">
      <h1> Hello </h1>
      <p> This is my amazing page </p>
    </div>

    <div class="other tab">
      <h1> art blah blag </h1>
      <p> This is my amazing page </p>
    </div>      
</div>

<script>
    $( "div.button" ).click(function() {
      $( "div.Home" ).toggleClass( "Show" );
      $( "div.Home" ).toggleClass( "tab" );
   });
</script>

<style>
   .tab
   {
      display: none;
   }
   .Show
   {
      display: block;
   }
</style>
```

This code contains my issue, simply put I want to click on button one and set home and then click on button 2 and set other etc. But I am new to Js and I cant seem to get it to work. I tried to use both buttons set home but that didn't work either.

Please help I am baffled.

Comment: You're using jQuery library functionality -- have you included that library in your page?

Comment: Its working here http://jsfiddle.net/x9fbwcah/. I believe you haven't included jquery library.

Comment: @Manwal: You omitted the CSS.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Yes actually i wanted to show jquery functionality. There is no special Css in OP's question so i omitted it.

Comment: I have not included the library how do I do so? and thank you for the replies

Comment: this code works perfect for me... check libraries and stylesheet ... linke them . it might work

Comment: @Kbcoder link that like normal js file... in script tag with correct path

Comment: Everyone...this code does not work correctly. The second link does not toggle the second "tab". Both buttons toggle the first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have in your post works, but not for the second button. You aren't toggling the visibility of the second "page".

After making sure you have included the jQuery library in your page (either from a CDN like in the example below, or you can download it yourself and use a local path instead), try something simpler (to maintain, IMO) like this:

```js
// on DOM-Ready
$(function() {
    // Listen for div.button clicks
    $("div.button").click(function() {
        // Hide any currently visible tabs
        $('div.tab').hide();
        // Get the target tab ID and show it
        $('#' + $(this).data('tab')).show();
    });
});
```

```css
 /* You don't need .show anymore */
 .tab {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- Note the addition of data-tab with the target tab ID -->
  <div id="one" data-tab="home" class="button">One</div>
  <div id="two" data-tab="other" class="button">Two</div>
</div>

<div>
  <!-- note the removal of special class names, using IDs instead -->
  <div class="tab" id="home">
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    <p>This is my amazing page</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" id="other">
    <h1> art blah blag </h1>
    <p>This is my amazing page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone who has replied I have learnt from this and I appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").show();
    $('.button').click(function(){                
        $('.tab').hide();
        $("#" + $(this).data('id')).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.tab{display: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div>   
            <div data-id="one" class="one button">1st tab</div>
            <div data-id="two" class="two button">2nd tab</div>       
        </div>

        <div>
            <div id="one" class="Home tab">
                <h1> Hello 1st tab is active</h1>
                <p> This is my amazing page </p>
            </div>

            <div id="two" class="other tab">
                <h1> art blah blag </h1>
                <p> This is my amazing page </p>
            </div>      
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery library in your code. Add this before script tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use JavaScript to click a `<div>` and change another `<div>`'s settings, you can follow these steps:

HTML: Create the two `<div>` elements and assign them unique IDs. For example:

JavaScript: Define a function to handle the click event and modify the settings of the second . You can use the `getElementById` method to access the DOM elements by their IDs, and then modify their properties or styles. For example:

```js
function changeSettings() {
  var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
  div2.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  div2.style.color = 'white';
  div2.innerHTML = 'Settings changed!';
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="changeSettings()" role="button">Click me</div>
<div id="div2">This div's settings will change</div>
```

In this example, the function `changeSettings()` changes the background color, text color, and inner HTML content of the second `<div>`.

CSS: You can also apply additional CSS styles to the `<div>` elements through external stylesheets or inline styles.
That's it! Now, when the first `<div>` is clicked, it will trigger the `changeSettings()` function, which modifies the properties of the second `<div>`.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT